# obtaining correct IMU values

Tags: python, imu

I am reading data from an AHRS / IMU sensor via USB with Python 2.7. To obtain the acceleration the manufacturer specifies according to the image below:

supplier's description IMU

[image]

My code in python is this, but when the acceleration is negative the values are wrong.
I believe I need to check the first bit of the MSB (In this case, the AxH field), if 1 is negative, if 0 is positive.

```
    #....
    #data = serial.read(size=11)
    #....
    #

    #Acceleration
    elif data[1] == b'\x51':
        AxL=int(data[2:3].encode('hex'), 16)
        AxH=int(data[3:4].encode('hex'), 16)
        AyL=int(data[4:5].encode('hex'), 16)
        AyH=int(data[5:6].encode('hex'), 16)
        AzL=int(data[6:7].encode('hex'), 16)
        AzH=int(data[7:8].encode('hex'), 16)

        x = (AxH<<8|AxL)/32768.0*16.0
        y = (AyH<<8|AyL)/32768.0*16.0
        z = (AzH<<8|AzL)/32768.0*16.0
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

The complete IMU sensor manual is this:
http://wiki.wit-motion.com/english/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=module:wt901:docs:jy901usermanualv4.pdf

Comment: There is no need to convert the data to a hex string, and then convert it back to an int. If you index a `bytes` object in Python3, you get the (unisgned) byte as an int directly, so you can just use `AxL = data[2]`. In Python2 you'd have to do `AxL = ord(data[2])`.

Comment: See my answer, the signed number representation of the shorts in the data is likely [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so just using the MSB as a sign bit is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

The axes data are stored as a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) [signed short (2 byte) integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)), so we can use [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to unpack the data. The `struct` module will take care of the correct interpretation of the `bytes` as short integers.

```
import struct

g = 9.81
conv = 16.0 / 32768.0 * g

# ...

    elif data[1] == b'\x51':
        axes = struct.unpack("<hhh", data[2:8])
        x, y, z = [a*conv for a in axes]
```

### Conversion by hand

If you want to do the conversion yourself, I'd assume that the representation of the signed number is [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
def twos_complement(x, bytes=2):
    maxnum = 2**(bytes*8) - 1
    msb = 1 << (bytes*8 - 1) 
    return -((x^maxnum) + 1) if x&msb else x

AxL = data[2]
AxH = data[3]
Ax_unsigned = AxH << 8 | AxL
Ax = twos_complement(Ax_unsigned, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but still may help someone.

We also should check out the length of the data received and check if the sum is correct. It is a good practice to make sure that the signal is received entirely.

As it is mentioned in the documentation, `Checksum： Sum=0x55+0x51+AxH+AxL+AyH+AyL+AzH+AzL+TH+TL`. It should be equal to the last value in data. So, do not forget to check it: `(sum(data) - data[10]) & 0xFF)`.